# Подключение к БД по несколько раз

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, база-данных, pyqt5

Работаю с PyQt5, есть форма состоящая из строки и кнопки. Записываем текст в строку, нажимаем на кнопку, а та подключается к БД и записанную строку добавляет в БД или дает нам знать, что запись существует. Скрипт работает, но БД открывается и закрывается по несколько раз. Что я делаю не так?

```
def sql_cnt_categ(self):
    text = self.per # сохраняю в переменную текст
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='111',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='data')

    try:
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        print('base opened')
        cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO categories (category) VALUES """ + "('%s')" % text + """;""")
        cnx.commit()
        print('Added')

    except Exception as e: #если записи нет, то добавляю
        print(e)
        self.error.setText('%s already exists' % text) # в оконной форме пишу что запись существует
        self.error.adjustSize()

    finally:
        cnx.close()
        print('base closed')
```

Comment: Что бы я не вводил, никогда не пишет ни ошибку, ни то что запись добавлена

Comment: А откуда вы знаете, что в блоке except при выполнении `cursor.execute(` исключения не произошли? Приложение случаем не падает при выполнении этого кода?

Comment: А там не слишком много кавычек на квадратный сантиметр? Что если попробовать так: `cursor.execute("SELECT category FROM categories WHERE category = '%s'" % text)` ?

Comment: @gil9red Нет, все работает, могу по несколько раз записи новые делать, вывод один и тот же

Comment: @nobody все тоже самое, программа несколько раз подключается и отключается

Answer (score 0):

Данные скорее всего заносятся в БД, но они не подтверждены, необходимо закоммитить транзакцию (`cnx.commit()`).

В руководстве имеется полный пример вставки данных:
[Inserting Data Using Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)